# Moodle -home page only displaying a database error after adding blocks and/or plugin installation

Tags: database, moodle

On Moodle, the home page (only) is not loading with the following error:

https://moodle.teachyourselfpython.com/

```
Error
Error reading from database
```

I am able to get into the admin and tried to un-install any recent plugins (global chat was one I had added and it hadn't worked) but still nothing works. All I was doing, to the best of my knowledge, was playing around with adding blocks and had added a poll option and global chat plugin to the home page.

I'd like to know how to a) Find the last few things I changed on some sort of moodle log and identify what it was that broke the system b) Fix the issue by hopefully de-installing plugins.

I cannot currently find a way to "get into" the home page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add debugging to `config.php`

```
// Force a debugging mode regardless the settings in the site administration
@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');    // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!

$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;             // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
```

Then copy and paste the error into the question above